# blazor js interop not selecting a html element

Tags: blazor

I have this simple method that's suppose to select a checkbox on the page then toggle the sidebar accordingly.

```
function toggleSidebar() {
  var cbx = document.getElementById("toggler-in-sidebar");
  console.log(cbx);                                      //this line display null.
  //console.log("Is checkbox checked: " + cbx.checked);
}
```

**alert()**, **console.log()** works, but selecting with **getElementById()** element that's on the page is returning *null*.

Here's my razor page

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__header">
        <div class="sidebar__header__logo">
            Logo
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar__header__toggler">
            <label for="toggler-in-sidebar" class="sidebar__toggler__label">&equiv;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggler-in-sidebar" class="sidebar__toggler__checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar__content">
        Sidebar content
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
    <header class="header">
        Header
    </header>
    <div class="page">
        @Body
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 @code {
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleSidebar");
  }
 }
```

Here's the reference in the index.html page

```
<body>
  <app>Loading...</app>

  <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
  <script src="js/toggle-sidebar.js"></script>
</body>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a pretty simple fix. During your OnInitialized method, the DOM isn't included because it doesn't exist quite yet. You need to hook into another lifecycle method, `OnAfterRenderAsync`, and what it will do is wait for the DOM to render, so it is all available, and *THEN* chase your element by ID for your interop. So just change your @code to:

```cs
@code {
  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleSidebar");
  }
 }
```

This should get you going, and then you can also use an `if` statement in the OnAfterRenderAsync method to execute your JS only on first render, or only on *not* first render, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the life-cycle is a little different from angular. I need to spend some time learning the difference between them. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

In Blazor, the default `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"`

The actual initial markup of your component gets resolved on server and sends down to the browser.

The browser initially sees the pre-rendered HTML and then the interactivity takes over.

During pre-rendering there is no browser, so there is no JavaScript, therefore you can't interop with JavaScript.

And if you do JSInterop, make sure to do call on `OnAfterRenderAsync` and **NOT** on `OnInit` or `OnParameterSet`.

Because `OnAfterRenderAsync`  do not run during pre-rendering.
Make Async calls while calling JSInterop then only it works with WebAssembly and Blazor server as well, because in case of Blazor server the call takes place over network so it has to be async call.

Hope it clarifies your doubt on life-cycle/flow!